# Properties of inner product and orthogonal vectors.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $X$ be Hilbert space. Prove the following statements are equivalent:

1) $x \perp y, $ $x,y \in X$

2) $||x||\le||x+ty||$ for every $t\in \mathbb{C}$

3) $||x-ty||=||x+ty||$

Obtaining 2) from 1) was fairly easy. However I can't find proper way using inner product to get 3) from 2).

Comment: Assuming $1$, when you expand $||x + ty||^2$, you get $||x||^2 + t^2 ||y||^2$. This is not equivalent to $2$.

Comment: @maq 2) implies $y=0$ there is some mistake in Your question.

Comment: $||x-ty||=||x+ty||=||x||$

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, actually, it should be $|t|^2$, not $t^2$.

Comment: @Ennar You are correct, thank you for pointing that out. But the mistake still remains... oh, the question's been edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $$\|x\pm ty\|^2 = \|x\|^2 \pm 2\operatorname{Re}(t\langle y,x\rangle) + |t|^2\|y\|^2\tag{*}$$

$\underline{1)\implies 2)}$

From $(*)$ we get $\|x+ty\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + |t|^2\|y\|^2\geq \|x\|^2$ for all $t\in\Bbb C$.

$\underline{2)\implies 1)}$

From $(*)$ and $(2)$ we get $2\operatorname{Re}(t\langle y,x\rangle) + |t|^2\|y\|^2\geq 0$ for all $t\in\Bbb C$. Let $t = \lambda\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb C$.

Assuming $\langle x,y\rangle \neq 0$, we have

\begin{align}
2\operatorname{Re}(t\langle y,x\rangle) + |t|^2\|y\|^2\geq 0 &\implies
2\operatorname{Re}(\lambda|\langle x,y\rangle|^2) + |\lambda|^2|\langle x,y\rangle|^2\|y\|^2\geq 0\\
&\implies
2\operatorname{Re}\lambda + |\lambda|^2\|y\|^2\geq 0,\ \forall\lambda\in\Bbb C
\end{align}

For real $\lambda$ this means that $$\lambda(\lambda\|y\|^2+2)\geq 0.$$ Now choose any $\lambda \in (-\frac 2{\|y\|^2}, 0)$ to arrive at contradiction.

$\underline{1)\iff 3)}$

From $(*)$ we have that $\|x-ty\| = \|x+ty\|$ if and only if $\operatorname{Re}(t\langle y, x\rangle) = 0$. Thus, $1)$ obviously implies $3)$.

Now assume that $\operatorname{Re}(t\langle y, x\rangle) = 0$, for all $t\in\Bbb C$. For $t = 1$, we get $\operatorname{Re}(\langle y, x\rangle) = 0$, while for $t = -i$ we get $\operatorname{Im}(\langle y, x\rangle) = \operatorname{Re}(-i\langle y, x\rangle) = 0$. Thus, $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$.